# Smaller subplots still visible under the subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

What could be the reason there are smaller subplots under the larger subplot?

I have followed the generic guide of matplotlib documentation https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/arranging_axes.html#axes-spanning-rows-or-grids-in-a-grid
but something didn't work along the way.

[image]

Code I used:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, n, figsize=(15, 7), layout='constrained')
spec = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=n, nrows=2)
fig.set_size_inches(15, 10)
fig.set_constrained_layout_pads(w_pad=0.8, h_pad=0.5, wspace=0, hspace=0)

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, :])
other_axes = [fig.add_subplot(spec[1, k]) for k in range(n)]

ax1 = ax0.twinx()
ax1.set_ylabel("Standard deviation")

for i in range(n):
       matrix = np.random.rand(5, 5)

       other_axes[i].imshow(matrix, cmap='viridis', interpolation='nearest')
       other_axes[i].set_title(f'blah {i + 1}')

ax0.set_xlabel("Episode number")
ax0.set_ylabel("blah")

ax1.plot(standard_deviation_line, label = "Title", linestyle='--', color='black')

ax0.set_title("blah")
for i in range(n):
    ax0.plot(lines[i], label=f"Blah")
ax0.legend(loc='upper right', framealpha=1)
ax1.legend(loc='upper left', framealpha=1)

plt.subplots_adjust(right = 0.8, wspace=0.3, hspace=0.3)
plt.figtext(0.97, 0.5, parameter_text, va='center', ha='right', fontsize=10)
```

Comment: The issue of smaller subplots being visible under the larger subplot could be related to the placement and layout of the subplots within the figure.

Comment: What do you want as a final result? Do you want to get rid of smaller subplots or make them bigger or ..? If the former - then don't add them here `fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, n, figsize=(15, 7), layout='constrained')` and here `other_axes = [fig.add_subplot(spec[1, k]) for k in range(n)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding subplots inside subplots. Change:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, n, figsize=(15, 7), layout='constrained')
```

To:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7), layout='constrained')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete subfigures, using `ax0.remove()`. The space/area that they occupied is kept -- this turned out to be quite useful for many layout issues for me.